# How To Fix Next.js Freeze (Cannot Scroll) On Mobile View After Navigating To A Different Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, bootstrap-5

I have detected a weird bug on mobile view on my Next.js + Bootstrap demo project. On mobile phone, use the burger menu to navigate to a new page and then try to scroll down. It sticks/freezes/hangs and I don’t know why. I have tried everything to resolve the problem but no progress. Any ideas?
Link to the source code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-lezt1f

Thanks

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In `layout.tsx` just add `overflow: 'visible'` and it will work

```
// layout.tsx
style={{ width: '100%', height: '0.5rem', overflow: 'visible' }}
```